# Op-Amp voltage follower with a capacitor in feedback

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image]

In some designs I've seen a voltage follower setup with a capacitor in the feedback path of the op-amp instead of just a straight short to the inverting pin.

- Does this have some sort of extra benefit since it doesn't allow current to flow into the non-inverting pin?
- Are there downsides to a setup like this?

Adding a picture of where I saw this for the first time.

[image]

Comment: This is not a "real world" circuit, there needs to be a DC-path to the - input of the opamp even if the opamp doesn't take any input current, the capacitor will have its charge "trapped" on the plate connected to the opamp's - input. The voltage will be undefined. Weird and unexpected behavior **will happen**. Note how all real "integrator" circuits will have a resistor in parallel with that capacitor.

Comment: I have seen this appear in multiple real world circuits.

Comment: *I have seen this appear in multiple real world circuits.* No you have not but please prove me wrong by including a link. Maybe you haven't always seen a parallel resistor but then there will be another path for the capacitor to charge/discharge.

Comment: https://www.eevblog.com/forum/projects/general-purpose-power-supply-design-7488/

Comment: Even if you don't believe me or that design I sent... Try it out yourself... Simulate it even....

Comment: I don't have to simulate this. What about resistor R6 ? Your circuit: - input of opamp has **only a capacitor** connected. EEVBlog circuit: - input of opamp has **a capacitor and a resistor (R6)** connected.

Comment: Even with R6 connected, what is the point of the capacitor?

Comment: So you admit that the actual circuit and your circuit are not the same? Hmm. What C8 is for: have a guess! And that's a different question. I have my idea but you were so convinced that your circuit works that I'm not going to tell you. Have you read the whole thread on the EEVBlog?

Comment: It's certainly not a voltage follower.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I found the original circuit I saw this on.  https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sbaa332/sbaa332.pdf
I've seen the same configuration of the unity gain buffers connected to the VRef-F/S on the DAC except on a different commercial design... however the designer additionally placed a feedback capacitor.  I believe he did this to minimize noise between the two pins (not sure if it was a futile attempt).  I didn't realize those pins were internally shorted, so there's your additional feedback path.

Comment: The interesting part to me was that I was able to get the original circuit I posted to be stable in LTSPICE by just giving the feedback capacitor a 100G of parallel resistance (Which I'm assuming would be near the amount of parallel resistance in some real world caps).  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I posted a crude pic of it for you.  Blowing on the cap would if it did lower the parallel resistance like that would actually make it work fairly better in that arrangement according to the simulations I've done.
Anyways, like I said, I didn't realize those two pins you see in the picture are shorted together.  I see now where I went wrong.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a voltage follower, it's not an [integrator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Op_amp_integrator) either. It's not clear what the circuit does.

Note the opamp negative input always sinks or sources a tiny amount of current, so you can't use only a capacitor in the feedback loop, or the input current will slowly charge it until the opamp saturates and the circuit becomes useless. So there needs to be a DC path from the "-" for this current to flow. Usually it's a resistor in parallel with the cap, or some other circuit.

If you're talking about the [schematic](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/projects/general-purpose-power-supply-design-7488/msg98794/#msg98794) in this forum post which you linked in the comments, this is not the same as the one in the question.

[image]

- R6 provides a path to ground for opamp input current
- R6 makes it an integrator ; if the opamp is in linear mode then voltage at both inputs is the same, which is set by the output of U3. This sets the current flowing into R6 and thus the dv/dt at the output of U4 which integrates this current into C8.

Note this circuit would not work on its own because nothing sets the DC operating point. It would keep integrating until the opamp clips. In this case this is handled by the rest of the circuit which loops around this portion and does set the DC operating point.

So:

- Without a DC path to ground for input current, the circuit in the question will not work.
- A resistor across the feedback cap solves this and also sets the DC operating point, which means the circuit can work stand-alone. It wouldn't do anything useful, to get an integrator you need to input a current into the "-" input, not a voltage though.
- Without a resistor across the feedback cap, the circuit can only work as a block inside a larger feedback loop that sets its DC operating point, otherwise it will keep integrating until it clips.

Comment: Even with a resistor across the cap it is NOT an integrator. It is a unity gain amplifier. Without this resistor the circuit does not work. The gain of such a non-inv. circuit is always (1+Z2/Z1). However, in the given circuit we have Z1 approaching infinity.

Comment: This circuit can in fact work in the real world because neither the op-amp nor the capacitor are ever ideal components.

Comment: *This circuit can in fact work in the real world because neither the op-amp nor the capacitor are ever ideal components.* Then please explain what non-ideal properties of the components make this circuit work. Also explain why I should not use the commonly know voltage follower circuit, where the output of the opamp connects directly to the - input (no capacitor needed).

Comment: This circuit will not work *unless there is a DC bias path for both the inverting and non-inverting input*. I have used a circuit of this type (as part of an overall compensation loop) and I had to ensure that such a bias path existed.

Comment: "Then please explain what non-ideal properties of the components make this circuit work."
The capacitor actually has a finite DC resistance and can leak current.  The op-amp has a finite amount of current it can sink into its input pins.

Comment: What if the opamp sinks more current than the capacitor can leak? Tread carefully, I have over 30 years of circuit design experience and so do many others here. So if your answer is BS we would smell it. You're losing points already. It is OK to not know (we're all here to learn something, yes even the old farts like myself) but don't make stuff up as we will spot that easily.

Comment: Please understand me.  I'm not proposing this as a design.  In fact it may be a terrible design, but I have seen it once before in my career the way I've shown it in the photo and again (though not exactly the same as you pointed out) in the design I linked to you.  This may have been a mistake by a designer at my company and I was just asking to make sure this was not a special circuit that I was unaware of.  It seemed to be a bad idea to me all around.

Comment: @LvW you're right lol, I misread the schematic in the question

Comment: *It seemed to be a bad idea to me all around* Hmm, while earlier: *This circuit can in fact work in the real world because....* In the EEVBlog circuit you missed a detail (R6), maybe you missed something in the other design as well.

Comment: Note if the opamp is current-feedback then the circuit will probably do... something.

Comment: I've corrected the answer.

Comment: @bobflux I appreciate your answer.